# Conflicts between 2 apps

Tags: android

I made my first app which is still on the emulator. So while testing out the second, I run it. The splash screen does it's job and then instead of going to the main activity of the app I'm testing, the app exits and a message comes up saying, complete the action by choosing either the first app or the second app I'm testing. So how do I avoid this or make the app not give the user that option?

EDIT:

APP 1:

MANIFEST:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.hellhog.tfreq"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >      
    <activity 
    android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
    android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" >        
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com.hellhog.tfreq.Splash"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.hellhog.tfreq.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAINACTIVITY" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

SPLASHSCREEN CODE:

```
package com.hellhog.tfreq;

import com.hellhog.tfreq.R;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;

public class Splash extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);
    MediaPlayer hog = MediaPlayer.create(Splash.this, R.raw.smusic);
    hog.start();

    Thread timer = new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            try{
                sleep(6000); 
            }catch (InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace(); 
            }finally{
                Intent openSplashLayout = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAINACTIVITY"); 
                startActivity(openSplashLayout); 
            }
        }
    };
    timer.start();  
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    finish();
}



 }
```

APP 2 :
MANIFEST:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.hellhogone.multitools"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="10" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.front" android:required="false" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.hellhogone.multitools.Splash"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
     <activity
        android:name="com.hellhogone.multitools.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAINACTIVITY" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.hellhogone.multitools.FlashLight"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.FLASHLIGHT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.hellhogone.multitools.Mirror"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MIRROR" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

SPLASHSCREEN:

```
package com.hellhogone.multitools;

import com.hellhogone.multitools.R;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;

public class Splash extends Activity{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN); 
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);

    MediaPlayer yo = MediaPlayer.create(Splash.this, R.raw.smusic); 
    yo.start(); 

    Thread timer = new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            try{
                sleep(6000);
            }catch(InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }finally{
                Intent h1 = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAINACTIVITY");
                startActivity(h1); 
            }
        }
    };

    timer.start(); 
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    finish(); 
}



    }
```

Comment: change package of both activty...

Comment: Could you post code, how you you start main activity and manifest files of 2 applications

Comment: May be you have specified some action in both app's activities' intent filter. Post both manifest files so we can get some idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for this is both your app are different(means with different package names), While in your Androidmanifest file of both applications you have specified same intent-filter for your MainActivity. Please consider adding different intent-filters in both app.

```
    <activity android:name="MainActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.yourcustom.intent"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

As in above example **com.example.yourcustom.intent** is intent filter registered for **MainActivity**
Whenever you fires an intent, for handle that intent Android will do **[intent-resoltuion](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html#ires)** and give you option of all apps which can handle that intent, thats why you are getting application chooser dialog.